# Arrays and Increment Operators in C?

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

This is a sample code I have from someone and it runs giving the answers

> 3, 2, 15

Can someone please explain how this piece of code works and how it got to those outputs?

Code:

```
int a[5] = { 5, 1, 15, 20, 25 };
int i, j, m;
i = ++a[1];
j = a[1]++;
m = a[i++];
printf("%d, %d, %d", i, j, m);
_getch();
```

Comment: Get *what* output? And what output did you expect?

Comment: Also, [this operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) might help you understand it a little.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, his output is in the second line of the post `3, 2, 15`.  He doesn't expect output, he would like to understand where it came from.

Comment: @user1717828 The output wasn't clear in the original post before the edit, and I'm sure the OP expected *something*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should know about *pre-increment* (`++var`) and *post-increment* (`var++`).

Let's break down the code line by line, shall we?

1. `i = ++a[1];` Here, `a[1]` is `1`, (2nd element of array `a`), is pre-incremented to `2` and that value is stored into `i`.
2. `j = a[1]++;` same, the `2` is stored into `j` and then `a[1]` is post-incremented to the value `3`.
3. `m = a[i++];` `a[2]`, i.e., `15` is stored into `m`, and `i` is post-incremented to `3`.
4. `printf("%d, %d, %d", i, j, m);` -- Surprise!!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly so:

- **Pre- ** Increment:  increment the value in the variable, then use the incremented value.
- ** Post- ** Increment:  grab the value and use it.  *After* grabbing the not-yet-incremented value, increment the value that's stored in the variable.  Proceed, using the value as it was before.

"Operator precedence" rules mean that, for example, `++a[1]` means that the meaning of `a[1]` will be resolved first, then the `++` operator will be applied to *that* memory-location.  The value of the number-one element (which is actually the *second* element ...) will be incremented, and the incremented value will be returned for use by the statement.

Answer (score -1):

1. `a[1]` refers to the second element which is `1`
2. In the step `i=++a[1]`,`a[1]` is incremented to `2` and assigned to `i`
3. in the next step `a[1]` is incremented again and the value of `a[1]` is incremented again to `3`
4. in the third step,`m=a[i++]`, value of  `i` is `2` from step 1 , but it is a post increment .so, `m` will remain `m=a[2]`